# Filtering FREETEXTTABLE output by rank for optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to optimize the following query which returns products matching search phrase:

```
WITH [RankedQuery] AS
(
    SELECT FTS.RANK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FTS].RANK DESC) AS [RowNumber], [Product].*
    FROM [Product]
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE([Product], 
    (
        [Name],
        [Brand],
        [Category],
        [Description]
    ), 'man shoes') AS [FTS]
    ON FTS.[Key] = [Product].[Id]
)
SELECT * FROM [RankedQuery]
WHERE [RowNumber] BETWEEN 100 AND 150
```

I found in the execution plan that it spends most time sorting the results by `RANK` - which makes sense, as it has to go through many rows that are not really necessary.

[image]

I tried to optimize it by filtering the products by rank before sorting, but the results were poor.

The query:

```
WITH [RankedQuery] AS
(
    SELECT MaxRelevance, FTS.RANK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FTS].RANK DESC) AS [RowNumber], [Product].*
    FROM [Product]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        select * from
        (   
            select FTS_stage_1.*, max(FTS_stage_1.rank) over() as MaxRelevance 
            from FREETEXTTABLE
            ([Product], 
                (
                    [Name],
                    [Brand],
                    [Category],
                    [Description]
                ), 'man shoes'
            ) 
            as FTS_stage_1
        ) AS [FTS_with_MaxRelevance]
        where [FTS_with_MaxRelevance].Rank > [FTS_with_MaxRelevance].MaxRelevance * 0.3 
    ) AS [FTS]
    ON FTS.[Key] = [Product].[Id]
)
SELECT * FROM [RankedQuery]
WHERE [RowNumber] BETWEEN 100 AND 150
```

resulted in this monstrosity, and a couple times longer execution time.

[image]

Is there a way to make it more efficient?